# How do we align text within a mat-button to the left?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

How do we align the text in an Angular Material button to the left?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452737/how-can-i-left-align-the-text-in-an-angular-material-stretched-md-button) suggest `text-align:left`?

And I tried it in this demo, however no love ...

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lcnasu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Findex.html

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `.mdc-button` uses `display: inline-flex;` you will have to use `justify-content: flex-start;` to align the text to the left.

See below:

```html
<button style="width: 10rem; justify-content: flex-start;" mat-raised-button>Basic</button>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rrp1jh?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Awesome!!  You rock!!